# Screen dims slightly when nothing moves at the screen... What do I do?

Tags: display, screen, brightness

I'm on Ubuntu Studio 19.10, fresh install. The display dims ever so slightly 1 second after everything stops moving at the screen. It goes like 1% darker, enough for being an annoying event when reading / working.

For example moving the mouse, typing, playing video or animation, a pop-up or menu appearing... basically anything that moves "wakes up" the screen for a second, then when everything becomes still, it fades slightly, and colors change a little..

I searched for screen, dimming, backlight, etc.. But I always end up in answers that mention power and screen locking options, which is definitely not the solution for my problem. Already had some trouble setting up the video drivers. After googling and fiddling, `nvidia-prime` seemed to correct blank screen at startup, but now I have this... It seems like the screen "winks" when everything stops.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of screen; laptop? A 1% change after 1 second is a little hard to discern. Is it 2% darker after 2 seconds?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix yes, it is a laptop! Dell Inspiron 3442. No, the 1% is an approximation just to get the idea. It mantains that same brightness until something moves again. You know, I thought about having some "gif like" icon or something in the panel that moves all the time... but that would be kind of stupid. I want to solve the problem correctly. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of busy so can't fully research for you but something like this will get you started on your analysis: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/screen-flickering-on-laptop-dell-inspiron-3442-a-4175667024/ In the end you will find your solution by more targeted questions like mentioning your laptop and googling on it.